# MATLAB fplot3 command

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I wanted to plot the 3D surface ((e^-t)sint,(e^-t)cost,1) using the following code.

```
x=(exp(-t))*sin(t); y=(exp(-t))*cos(t); z=1;
    fplot3(x,y,z)
```

I received this error message:

```
Error using fplot3 (line 46)
Expected input to be one of these types:

function_handle, sym

Instead its type was double.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says `fplot3` doesn't take numerical values. Use symbolic functions instead.

```
x = @(t) exp(-t).*sin(t);
y = @(t) exp(-t).*cos(t);
z = @(t) t*0 + 1;
fplot3(x,y,z);
```